# Websocket doesn't connect despite socket io server running

Tags: php, laravel, websocket, socket.io

I'm using socket io + Redis + Laravel event

checklist:

- redis server started.
- redis client responding to 'ping'
- port 6379 is open and not blocked

**server.js**

```
'use strict';
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
require('dotenv').config();

var redisPort = process.env.REDIS_PORT;
var redisHost = process.env.REDIS_HOST;

var ioRedis = require('ioredis');
var redis = new ioRedis(redisPort, redisHost);
redis.subscribe('action-channel-one');
redis.on('message', function (channel, message) {
  message  = JSON.parse(message);
  console.log(message);
  io.emit(channel + ':' + message.event, message.data);
});

var broadcastPort = process.env.BROADCAST_PORT;
server.listen(broadcastPort, function () {
  console.log('Socket server is running.');
});
```

**client.php**

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.2.0/socket.io.js"> </script>
<script>

  var sock = io('{{ env("PUBLISHER_URL") }}:{{ env("BROADCAST_PORT") }}', {transports: ["websocket"]});


  console.log(sock);
.................
```

Error:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Adding a BROADCAST_PORT = 3444 in .env and client side solved the issue. referign to this question: [socket io not established in live site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66263310/socket-io-not-established-in-live-site)